# Typescript Error with React Native Flat List

Tags: typescript, react-native, types

I am getting the following error when trying to use Typescript with a React Native Flat List:

```
Type '(item: navigationTypes) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ListRenderItem<unknown>'.
```

Here is my code:

```
type navigationTypes = {
  name: string
  href: string
}

const navigation = [
  { name: 'Support', href: '/support' },
  { name: 'Privacy Policy', href: '/privacy-policy' },
  { name: 'Terms Of Use', href: '/terms-of-use' },
  { name: 'Terms & Conditions', href: '/terms-&-conditions' },
]

  const Item = ({ title = '', href = '' }) => (
    <View>
      <Text>
        <TextLink href={href}>{title}</TextLink>
      </Text>
    </View>
  )

 const renderItem = (item: navigationTypes) => (
    <Item title={item.name} href={item.href} />
  )

       <View>
          <FlatList
            horizontal
            data={navigation}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
          />
        </View>
```

I'm new to Typescript so I'm struggling to understand why there is an issue here.

Answer (score 1):

The item is passed as the `item` property of an object to the `renderItem` function. Which means that your function signature is not correct.

If you wrote it inline, it would look like

```
renderItem={({ item }) => <Item title={item.name} href={item.href} />}
```

or

```
const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: navigationTypes }) => (
  <Item title={item.name} href={item.href} />
)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'm now getting this error:   Type error: No overload matches this call.

Answer (score 0):

`const obj = { a: 1, b: 2 };`

`const { a, b } = obj;`

`const renderItem = {(dataItem.item: navigationTypes) =>`

to avoid this we destructure our object like this.

{item} = dataItem;

we are destructuring the items passed to the renderItem function, and navigationTypes is its type.

`const renderItem = {({item}: navigationTypes) =>`

`( <Item title={item.name} href={item.href} /> )}`

```
   <View>
      <FlatList
        horizontal
        data={navigation}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
```

Comment: Would be great, if you explain the code!

Comment: const renderItem = ({item}: navigationTypes) => ( <Item title={item.name} href={item.href} />)